# MySQL select distinct but only if all of second col = 1?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I would like this to simply not return anything.  How can I do that?

```
mysql> select distinct (search_num), complete from Table where complete = '1';
+------------+----------+
| search_num | complete |
+------------+----------+
|       1825 |        1 |
+------------+----------+
```

Because actually there is one (or more) rows that is still 0 as shown:

```
mysql> select distinct (search_num), complete from Table;
+------------+----------+
| search_num | complete |
+------------+----------+
|       1825 |        1 |
|       1825 |        0 |
+------------+----------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a part of `select distinct` and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses to make the code clearer, i.e. simply write `select distinct search_num, complete ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach here is to aggregate by the `search_num`, and then assert that the only `complete` value which occurs is 1.

```
SELECT search_num
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY search_num
HAVING MIN(complete) = MAX(complete) AND MIN(complete) = 1;
```